# Omniture / Adobe Analytics tracking breaks external links in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, analytics, adobe-analytics

The Omniture tracking code is breaking all external links on our site in desktop and mobile Safari. When we click or tap on any link with an href outside our own domain, Safari won't open the page requested - or it does once, but then not again. Here's a very basic example of the kind of link that breaks:

```
<a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">Test</a>
```

This is a weird bug that only affects Safari. We know it's the Omniture code because the links start working as soon as we comment out the link to the SiteCatalyst JS file, or when we set the `s.trackExternalLinks` option in the Omniture config to `false`.

SiteCatalyst has a `linkInternalFilters` variable where we set the domain of our site: a function called `s.exitLinkHandler` uses this. We thought it might be the source of the issue, but even when we redefine it as an empty function our external links are still blocked.

Has anyone else come across this crazy problem? We can work around it for the moment by removing the href attributes of external links and handling clicks callbacks that use window.open, but it's a total pain that normal external links on our site now don't work on iPads, iPhones and desktop Safari.

(We're using version H.25.2.05feb2013 of SiteCatalyst.)

Comment: H.25 changed the timing logic for Safari because Safari would kill any current requests immediately when a page was left. There are likely several things at play here, so the best option would be to either talk to Adobe Client Care, or post a like to your implementation here so we can see all the parts.

Thanks C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll simply want to update your H code. There are several link tracking issues resolved in later code versions:

http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/release/index.html#JavaScript_H_code_Legacy

If you're using manual link tracking, you'll also want to slightly modify your implementation to accommodate recent browser updates:

http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#Manual_Link_Tracking_Using_Custom_Link_Code